I find myself locked in a room
Slowly I wake up, and I find myself locked in a room. I panic, and I know I have to find a way out.
I start exploring the room. When I look around, I see a large door on the east side of the room. I must have entered through that door, but I know there is no way back.
At the west side, the wall was plastered full of propaganda posters with loud slogans. I didn't like it at all.
At the south side, there is a bar. It used to be a lively bar that offered everything from signature drinks to a range of beers and appetizers. But now it's pretty dead. Nothing to see there anymore.
At the north side, there are a bunch of buttons and levers. It looks like they have each a special kind of function, but I have no idea. I shouldn't spend too much time to find out what each of them does—it probably won't help me.
Furthermore, there are 4 doors, one in each corner. The doors are all locked, but surely one of the doors should let you escape! But which one is it? There are some keys here and there, and I think one of them will unlock the right door. However, I  can't try the doors at random, cause I have a feeling that one of the doors is really dangerous. Once I open that door, I will be gone forever!
Which door leads to freedom and why?

Any native English speaker that thinks the grammar/sentences could be better, feel free to modify :)

Not native, but you probably want "too much" (double o) rather than "to much", unless the spelling is part of clues.

@MatthieuM., you're right, but that was just a typo :D

Did you mean to switch between first and second person so much?

The door to freedom is in...

 the northwest corner.

Because this room is modelled on...

 the layout of a computer keyboard (hence the mentions of 'keys')!



 You came in via the large Enter button on the right (the east) and saw function buttons (the F keys) at the top (north), the space bar - which sounds like an 'empty space' bar from the description! - at the bottom (south), and the in-your-face posters in the west are likely written in all capitals, hence the Caps Lock key on the left.

If you need to escape the room...

 you should probably use the Escape key in the top-left corner (north-west). Just don't go top-right (north-east) whatever you do - you might end up Deleted!!


Just curious, which corner door is dangerous?

@FirstNameLastName See what I wrote in the final sentence! :)

Sure. my bad: I had only quickly looked at picture where extreme corners looked not so scary as the one intended you mention :)

@FirstNameLastName, depends which layout is used. There are several layouts where the dangerous key is really the northeast corner, and not the elevator in this picture :)
